# Geolocation in Chrome custom tab android

Tags: android, geolocation, chrome-custom-tabs

I want a method like ongeolocationpermissionsshowprompt in webview to be used in chrome custom tabs, or a way to manage location permission by my side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Tabs will use the underlying browser permission system, so it's not possible manage permission in the native app side.

If you own/control the page being opened inside the application, you could use [Trusted Web Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trusted-web-activity/) with the [upcoming Location Delegation feature](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/pull/117).